# How to fix the datetime column which has string datetype?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column of dates but not all of the rows are DateTime type, some rows have string datatype, such as Jan'11, Jan 11, Jan-11. My idea is I wanna replace the split "'", and " " to be "-", then replace it to datetime format.

so this is the code that I tried,

```
replacers = {"'":"-"," ":"-"} 
df['Periode1'] = df['Periode1'].replace(replacers)
```

but when I check `df[df['Periode1']=="Jan'11"]` it still not change to be "Jan-11". So how to solve it?

Comment: Can you add sample data to reproduce the data frame for the test? Please [check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/8353711) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `.replace` method looks at the entire contents of each object in the series, and since there is more than just the separator in each date, the method does nothing. A better approach would be to apply a lambda function to the series:

```py
df['Periode1'] = df['Periode1'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("'", "-").replace(" ", "-"))
```